# Text Input should not lose focus if validation fails in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

In NewFormComponent, I have onBlur on first input which is checking if fname is "" then console "Validation failed"

Requirement: Textfield should not lose focus until the user enters some value or it should pass Validations. In other words, until the validation is passed user can't select or tab to other text fields in the same form.

I have tried using ref and calling focus() method, but it textfield to gain focus but user is still able to select other textfields.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class NewFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       fname:"",
       lname:""
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      })
  }
  onFormSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(`Hi ${this.state.fname} ${this.state.lname}`)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <input type="text"
                name="fname" 
                value={this.state.fname}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onBlur={()=>{
                    if(this.state.fname === ""){
                        console.log("Validation failed");
                    }
                }}
            />
            <input type="text"
             name="lname" 
             value={this.state.lname} 
             onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Expection: Textfield shouldn't lose focus until validation is passed

Comment: It would probably be a better user experience to disable the other inputs until validation is passed. That way there is a visual clue for the user that the first input needs to be filled

Comment: As @BrettGregson said, why not `autoFocus` the text field to begin with, and then programmatically set the `disabled` property of other fields via state? In your `handleChange` function, you could check if the string is empty there, and then set a piece of state called `inputValidated` to true or false. That value can be used to set `disabled` everywhere else, keeping in mind you'll have to negate it - so `disabled={!this.state.inputValidated}`. In the long run, however, and if this is a large component with many fields, you might be better of performing validation once on submit.

Comment: Thanks @Brett and @Jamie, I think using ```disabled``` attribute will solve the issue